# Why shouldn't I create a new user on Oracle SYSTEM Tabespace?

Tags: oracle

For example:

```
CREATE USER c##mybear IDENTIFIED BY pretty 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS 
QUOTA 500M ON SYSTEM;
```

So, Why shouldn't I create a new user on Oracle SYSTEM Tabespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle Documentation states:

> The default setting for the default tablespaces of all users is the
>   SYSTEM tablespace. If a user does not create objects, and has no
>   privileges to do so, then this default setting is fine. However, if a
>   user is likely to create any type of object, then you should
>   specifically assign the user a default tablespace, such as the USERS
>   tablespace. Using a tablespace other than SYSTEM reduces contention
>   between data dictionary objects and user objects for the same data
>   files. In general, do not store user data in the SYSTEM tablespace.

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/users.htm#i1006219) also explains how to create an alternative tablespace etc.